# Sql Server Deadlock issue with 3 processes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql server. I am facing deadlock issue in sql server. In deadlock graph it is showing due to 3 processes, deadlock happened. I am not able to understand the deadlock graph with 3 processes. Below is my deadlock graph. 
[image]

Below is deadlock xml :

```
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process2db5c28" />
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process2db5c28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 10:72057597892755456 (63eb251d860a)" waittime="11658" ownerId="5805847" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-02-10T18:12:06.793" XDES="0x336846d90" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="7860" status="suspended" spid="327" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2019-02-10T18:12:07.080" lastbatchcompleted="2019-02-10T18:12:07.073" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.073" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Test" hostpid="7716" loginname="test" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5805847" currentdb="10" currentdbname="test_Event_6701" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="320" stmtend="2784" sqlhandle="0x02000000c6cb1d04abdbec564d5b74a8bedb0851eaa773280000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
(@p0 bigint,@p1 datetime,@p2 datetime,@p3 bit,@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 nvarchar(4000),@p6 nvarchar(4000),@p7 nvarchar(4000),@p8 nvarchar(4000),@p9 nvarchar(4000))SELECT this_.Request_Id as Request1_190_0_, this_.Request_CreateDate as Request2_190_0_, this_.Request_IsSuccessful as Request3_190_0_, this_.Request_UpdateExistingPositionProduct as Request4_190_0_, this_.Request_UpdateCustomValidationCaching as Request5_190_0_, this_.Request_IsAnyHpcTaskInProgress as Request6_190_0_, this_.Request_ChangeTypes as Request7_190_0_, this_.IsSystemRequest as IsSystem8_190_0_, this_.SubmittedOn as Submitte9_190_0_, this_.EffectiveDate as Effecti10_190_0_, this_.ActionDate as ActionDate190_0_, this_.ActionType as ActionType190_0_, this_.RequestStatus as Request13_190_0_, this_.AuthorPositionId as AuthorP14_190_0_, this_.Title as Title190_0_, this_.LastComment as LastCom16_190_0_, this_.RequestCode as Request17_190_0_, this_.AuthorPersonnelId as AuthorP18_190_0_, this_.IsSyncedToReporting as IsSynce19_190_0_, this_.Personne   </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2dceca8" taskpriority="0" logused="256" waitresource="KEY: 10:72057597892755456 (63eb251d860a)" waittime="10583" ownerId="5802704" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-02-10T18:12:06.277" XDES="0x378b2b770" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="7732" status="suspended" spid="297" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2019-02-10T18:12:08.147" lastbatchcompleted="2019-02-10T18:12:08.107" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.107" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Test" hostpid="7716" loginname="test" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5802704" currentdb="10" currentdbname="test_Event_6701" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="826" sqlhandle="0x02000000c41a7b04756cb87d16131d008eb58c6f909659cd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
                <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
                <frame procname="test_Event_6701.dbo.UpdateAttributeValidationCache" line="47" stmtstart="4398" stmtend="4500" sqlhandle="0x03000a0018bc1b7e4fb42301f0a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
INSERT INTO #RequestRelation exec sp_executesql @sq    </frame>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="242" sqlhandle="0x01000a00f5251b0990bf48b00500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC UpdateAttributeValidationCache  @validationIds=@p0,@OrgUnitCacheHi=@p1,@RequestOrgUnitCacheHi=@p2, @RequestId=@p3, @AuthorPositionId=@p4,@eventStartDate=@p5,@eventEndDate=@p6    </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
(@p0 [dbo].[Int_List] READONLY,@p1 bigint,@p2 bigint,@p3 bigint,@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 nvarchar(4000),@p6 nvarchar(4000))EXEC UpdateAttributeValidationCache  @validationIds=@p0,@OrgUnitCacheHi=@p1,@RequestOrgUnitCacheHi=@p2, @RequestId=@p3, @AuthorPositionId=@p4,@eventStartDate=@p5,@eventEndDate=@p6   </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2c13848" taskpriority="0" logused="260956" waitresource="KEY: 10:72057597892755456 (ea7380e6da4f)" waittime="8719" ownerId="5769072" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-02-10T18:12:00.300" XDES="0x671eac3b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="7140" status="suspended" spid="306" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2019-02-10T18:12:10.020" lastbatchcompleted="2019-02-10T18:12:10.020" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.020" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Test" hostpid="7716" loginname="test" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5769072" currentdb="10" currentdbname="test_Event_6701" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="498" sqlhandle="0x020000001ffb721bb57eb5027444ed4d9184e816c11833120000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
                <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
                <frame procname="test_Event_6701.dbo.RunCustomerTypeRoleValidation" line="60" stmtstart="6434" stmtend="6536" sqlhandle="0x03000a008878d96e1cb42301f0a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
INSERT INTO #RequestRelation exec sp_executesql @sq    </frame>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="240" sqlhandle="0x01000a00a033940a409fb5b40500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC RunCustomerTypeRoleValidation  @ObjectTypeId=@p0, @RequestId=@p1,@batchId=@p2,@AuthorPositionId=@p3,@EffectiveDate=@p4,@EndDate=@p5,@isBatchChange=@p6    </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 bigint,@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 nvarchar(4000),@p6 smallint)EXEC RunCustomerTypeRoleValidation  @ObjectTypeId=@p0, @RequestId=@p1,@batchId=@p2,@AuthorPositionId=@p3,@EffectiveDate=@p4,@EndDate=@p5,@isBatchChange=@p6   </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057597892755456" dbid="10" objectname="test_Event_6701.dbo.Requests" indexname="PK_Requests" id="lock4b1a2c480" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057597892755456">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2c13848" mode="X" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2db5c28" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057597892755456" dbid="10" objectname="test_Event_6701.dbo.Requests" indexname="PK_Requests" id="lock4b1a2c480" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057597892755456">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2db5c28" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2dceca8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057597892755456" dbid="10" objectname="test_Event_6701.dbo.Requests" indexname="PK_Requests" id="lock64a436900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057597892755456">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2dceca8" mode="X" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2c13848" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Please someone help me understanding of this deadlock issue and how can I resolve it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you need to post the xml for the deadlock graph not just the picture

Comment: @MartinSmith :  Updated question with xml. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typical Reader-Writer deadlock. It states that there is a deadlock between a statement that is reading from `dbo.Requests` table and another statement that is performing some form of data modification on the same table. Easy fix for this form of deadlock is to use a row-version based isolation level, either `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` or `SNAPSHOT`

You can read more about this [Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

You can also try using `WITH(SERIALIZABLE)` when selecting any record from `dbo.Requests` table like following

```
select * from dbo.Requests WITH(SERIALIZABLE) where id=@id
```